# How to stop Skype from automatically using the loudspeaker

Tags: 8.0, skype, lumia-black-update, lumia-amber

I have been quite happy with Skype's performance on Windows Phone 8 except for one issue. When I place a call and the recipient picks up, it will automatically put the call on speaker, and there doesn't seem to be a button on the UI to change it to the earpiece, unless it's hidden somewhere.

It makes it a bit awkward in public places. I have tried various combinations of devices

1. Vodacom Lumia 1020 Lumia Black <-> Vodacom Lumia 1020 Lumia Amber
2. MTN Lumia 925 Lumia Black <-> Vodacom Lumia 1020 Lumia Black
3. Vodacom Lumia 1020 Lumia Amber <-> Windows 8.1 PC
4. Samsung Galaxy Note 8 Android 4.1.2 <-> Vodacom Lumia 1020 Lumia Amber

Is there a workaround which needs to be done to make the call use the earpiece? There are 5 WP8 phones in my house, making Skype quite useful and I don't want to have to stop using it.

Comment: Write a negative review on the Skype App in the store. They will issue an update

Comment: @cha I saw yesterday they released an update for Skype, but it hasn't appeared for my network yet. I noticed the last couple of times it will use the earpiece for about 5 seconds before switching to loudspeaker.

Comment: We only switch to the loudspeaker if the incoming call is a video call, or you answer yourself with video. We're aware this is less than ideal for certain situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I notice that apps like whatsapp switch from loudspeaker to earpiece speaker if you **hold the phone to your ear**.  It was so simple, I thought I had a weird bug where it would switch between the two, then I realized it works if I just hold it to my head.  Perhaps this is the same for Skype or for the media player in general on the phone?

Comment: Interesting. Will try it out

Comment: It works! Since the update Skype has been more reliable, and I guess it solved my issue as well. Thanks!

Comment: What you say about it using the earpiece for about 5 seconds first makes sense then, it's assuming you are holding it to your ear, then realizes you aren't and switches to loudspeaker :)

Comment: Actually it's related to if either party answers with video. You wouldn't hold a video call up to your ear, would you now?-)